# Set defaults values Urls Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, url

I'm using magento 1.9, I changed the values  of:

- URL Base of JavaScript: `{{unsecure_base_url}}js/`
- URL Base of Skin:`{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/`
- URL Base of Media:`{{unsecure_base_url}}media/`

  I deleted the values...
- URL Base of JavaScript: `{{unsecure_base_url}}`
- URL Base of Skin:`{{unsecure_base_url}}`
- URL Base of Media:`{{unsecure_base_url}}`

And I'll changed it again in the database, now it's ok, but there isn't CSS and Javascript , it's just HTML at the admin panel and the store.

You can check it here: [tienda.mabaonline.com](http://tienda.mabaonline.com)

I don't know what can I do, I want to restore the defaults values maybe that can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your skin url is wrong.
It should be `{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/`. For some reason you are missing `skin/` from it.
check the database `core_config_data` table and clear the cache.

You can even delete from the database the value for path `web/unsecure/skin_url`. it will default back to the value mentioned above.

Comment: I deleted it in the database, how can I clean the cache of magento?

Comment: remove the contents of folder `var/cache`. Just the contents, not the folder itself.

Comment: O yess that works!, Thank you very much, maybe you can tell where can I add my code to redirect urls?.